# Visual Studio 2017 different accounts for different deployments

Tags: visual-studio-2017, account, microsoft-account

I have Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise installed at work and I have a work account that I use for it. I thought that I can install Visual Studio 2017 Community on the same machine side-by-side and use it under my personal account.

I've tried adding my account to Visual Studio but it seems that signing out in one leads to being signed out in the other.

Is it possible to use work account for Enterprise and personal account for Community without any switching or account linking (like if I had two separated PCs)? And if yes, then how can it be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to accomplish what I wanted by creating a separate local Windows account and using it to run `devenv.exe` [as a different user](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490994.aspx). This way account information does not leak from Enterprise to Community, and vise versa.